# Searching on Multiple Fields using BST

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Suppose we need to create an address book that can provide search functionality on multiple fields, with a large number of records.  The structure is very simple – name, phone number and city name.

I can type "begin with Ron..." or "begin with 202..." or "begin with Arling..."

Then it will give me the expected results.

First solution come up to my mind is, create three BST, one based on phone number, one based on name, the third one based on city.

NOW I AM THINKING, is there a way to create one BST (or any other methods), but still make the search work, without sort it every time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your scenario is not clear. Do you need to support queries like "give me a record with name X and phone number Y" or just queries  like "give me a record where either the name or the city is X, I don't care which". The latter is trivial, the former is more contrived

Comment: Yes you are right, I will search one attribute at one time meet only one criterion, such as, give me all the city name begin with X, I will not need to query something meets two criterions at one time.

Comment: So what's the problem with using 3 BBSTs/Hash tables? It seems optimal

Comment: it is no problem using 3 BST, but I just want to know is there a way to avoid 3 BST or hash tables. I don't know whether it's optimal.

Comment: I don't see why you would use something else, since it's optimal both in asymptotical runtime and space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it with a single BST. The BST node would be:

```
class BSTNode
{
    string Key;
    byte KeyType; // 0=Name, 1=City, 2=Phone
    AddressRec Record;
}
```

And the `AddressRec` is of course a reference to the actual address record.

You end up having three entries in the BST for each record. So given an address record:

```
rec0 = { Name = "Jim", City = "Austin", Phone="512-555-1212" }
```

You would add the records:

```
BST.Add(rec0.Name, 0, rec0);
BST.Add(rec0.City, 1, rec0);
BST.Add(rec0.Phone, 2, rec0);
```

And your search would take the record type as a parameter.

This is easier to manage in that you only have one BST, but searching is going to be a little slower, but by a constant factor. Search in a BST is O(log n), and your combined BST is going to have three times as many nodes as the three special-purpose trees. Still, it's not linearly slower. That is, if you have 1,024 address entries then each of your special-purpose trees will have 1024 nodes. log2(1024) is 10. Your single tree will have 3,072 nodes. log2(3,072) is 11.58. So individual searches will be *slightly* slower.

Note, though, that it's slightly slower by a constant factor. Consider this table:

```
   n   log2(n)   log2(3n)
  16      4        5.58
 128      7        8.58
1024     10       11.58
2^20     20       21.58
```

On average the single tree will require approximately two extra probes per search, regardless of how many items are in the BST.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, learn a lot. May I ask how should I arrange the BST, say if I sort the BST based on phone number, all the smaller are on the left and larger are on the right, it's OK if I query "give me all the number start with 202", but how it works if I ask "give me all the records name start with Ron"

Comment: @XinruiMa: The tree isn't sorted by phone number or name. Phone number, name, and city are all individual keys in the tree. Re-read my answer. You would search for "202", for example, and output every record that starts with "202" and has a `KeyType` of 2. To search for the name "Ron" you do a search of the tree and output everything that starts with "Ron" and has a `KeyType` of 0. Make sense?